# Bootstrap Responsive : Show multiple div in collapse mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In bootstrap nav we can show the menu in collapsing format.
Similary I want to show div in the collasing format. e.g if it is is mobile view then only show the top div and hide all the div in collapse mode . I am aware of the below supports in bootstrap responsive

```
.visible-phone  
.visible-tablet 
.visible-desktop
.hidden-phone
.hidden-tablet
.hidden-desktop
```

If it is not supported please all share the idea how it can be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

**nirajkumar**, have a look at this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lzrag58n/)**.
You can use the `.hidden-xs`Bootstrap class to do what you want here.
Using version 3.3.4.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1 text-center block2 hidden-xs">
     Div #1
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-4 text-center block2">
     Div #2
</div>
```

Comment: I am aware of .hidden-xs (.visible-phone  ) and other things . I have already mentioned in the post. But what I really want is that how can I show only a certain part and on sliding/or some action show the other contents ..... just like in case of menu / we display a button for mobile device and hide the actual menu .....

Comment: Hi there, sorry there was no mention that you had tried `hidden-xs`. As far as I can get here you just want to switch something on or off at certain breakpoints. If so then just set up your own media queries breakpoints. And use `display:block;`and `display:none;` etc. Does this help?

Comment: actually I had mentioned ".visible-phone  " which is from the older version of bootstrap ... to explain what I am really looking for is ... instead of scaffolding bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html ... I want to the content to come with swipe .. or on some action not do scafffolding ........ so I was asking whether it is supported by the bootstrap .. instead of writing own logic ...

Comment: Switching something off/on.. it sounds like by the user...maybe. Have you looked at using a toggle.  Good luck with what you are looking to do here.

Answer (score 0):

This is listed in the official Bootstrap docs.  Here's the link: 
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes